# Batch file to execute command after process end

Tags: batch-file, process

I'm making a batch file that starts a program, for example `notepad.exe`. I need it to execute a command after I have closed `notepad.exe` manually.

I only know that in order to do this, the batch file will have to verify if the process `notepad.exe` is running or not.

How can I make it verify this exactly **when** I have closed the *Notepad* window manually?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `start`, you can `/wait` for the program to finish before running any more commands:

```
(commands)

start "" /wait notepad.exe

(commands to run here)
```

Replace `notepad.exe` with the path to the program. You can also add parameters after `notepad.exe` to pass to the program.

The program will wait for `notepad.exe` to close first before running the commands below.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **not** to do **anything**.

I'm guessing your currently using the `start` command. The thing is the `start` command starts the program and then continues on. If you call the program as an `"operable program or batch file"` then it will wait for the program to end before continuing.

You learn this stuff when automating batch commands and creating macros.

Say you wanted to run **notepad.exe** with a file named *file.txt* and then type it,

#### Simply :

```
notepad.exe file.txt
type file.txt
```

**No** `start`. If that's not it show us your code and then we may be able to tell you why.

Comment: Thanks, but for me, the `start "" /wait notepad.exe` works fine. I don't need the batch file to perform complex operations, it was just to move files from one directory to another and then, after the process end, bring them back